# How to Call package successfully

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

got error when calling package

error is

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
 PKG_Generate_GRNo.GenerateGR(TO_NUMBER(:P164_APP_ID,
 '9999999'),:APP_USER,:P164_FIRST_NAME,:P164_LAST_NAME,:P164_EMAIL,:P164_SKYPE_ID,:P164_COUNTRY,:P164_DATE_OF_BIRTH)
 Error report - Unknown Command

 PKG_Generate_GRNo.GenerateGR(TO_NUMBER(:P164_APP_ID,
'9999999'),:APP_USER,:P164_FIRST_NAME,:P164_LAST_NAME,:P164_EMAIL,
 :P164_SKYPE_ID,:P164_COUNTRY,:P164_DATE_OF_BIRTH);
```

Comment: I am calling this code in both sql developer or also in apex but when it calls it show error which is mention below                                                                                           
-----------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                               
Session state protection violation: This may be caused by manual alteration of protected page item P164_COURSECOUNT. If you are unsure what caused this error, please contact the application administrator for assistance.

Comment: For future reference please **edit your question** to include further details or to make other improvements.

Answer (score 1):

*Session state protection violation* is definitely an Apex error, relating to your page settings. It seems your package is trying to change the state of a read-only page. [See this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41845895/146325).

The item identifier in the error message `P164_COURSECOUNT` has the same prefix as the parameters you pass to the package (`:P164_APP_ID`) so presumably they relate to the same page. We know nothing about your application or its architecture, so it's hard to offer concrete advice. Maybe you need to change the page or item settings, maybe you need to change what the package does. Only you can tell the right course of action.

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't post the whole command, a note: you have to enclose it into `begin-end` block, e.g.

```
BEGIN
   PKG_Generate_GRNo.GenerateGR (TO_NUMBER ( :P164_APP_ID, '9999999'),
                                 :APP_USER,
                                 :P164_FIRST_NAME,
                                 :P164_LAST_NAME,
                                 :P164_EMAIL,
                                 :P164_SKYPE_ID,
                                 :P164_COUNTRY,
                                 :P164_DATE_OF_BIRTH);
END;
/
```