# Session state protection violation for display only item - Oracle APEX 19.2.0.00.18

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I set te value of a Display Only item in a True Action
using the instruction apex_util.set_session_state('P14_NUCUEN', cuen.Nucuen);

My problem is that when I submit the form it shows the error "Session state protection violation: This may be caused by manual alteration of protected page item P14_NUCUEN. If you are unsure what caused this error, please contact the application administrator for assistance."

The Session State protection of P14_NUCUEN is set to Unrestriscted and I even set Session State Protection to Disabled in Application Security Attributes to check if that fixes the problem, but error is still there.

I have seen solutions refered to hidden items that surely work but the solution exposed in [Can't disable session state protection on Oracle APEX 18.1.0.00.45 for Dynamic Actions updating Page Items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55613090/cant-disable-session-state-protection-on-oracle-apex-18-1-0-00-45-for-dynamic-a) did not work for me

Answer (score 3):

In case someone is googling the same issue: You have to deactivate the option "Send On Page Submit" under settings.