# Oracle APEX 21.2 - Session Protection Error for Disabled Textfield Loaded By Dynamic Action

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a modal form that, when the 'Lookup User' button is clicked, a Dynamic Action fetches user information from an external source and sets session state for the page items on the page. Outside of the 'username', all other fields are disabled, but should still be submitted on page submit (page process) to be part of the DML. Here is the Dynamic Action PL/SQL code:

```sql
select employee_id
      ,last_name
      ,first_name
      ,email
 into r_ldap_user
 from ...;

apex_util.set_session_state('P65_EMPLOYEE_ID', r_ldap_user.employee_id);
apex_util.set_session_state('P65_FIRST_NAME', r_ldap_user.last_name);
apex_util.set_session_state('P65_LAST_NAME', r_ldap_user.first_name);
apex_util.set_session_state('P65_EMAIL', r_ldap_user.email);
```

The Dynamic Action loads the form with the data correctly, but:

1. looking at the session window, there is no session state for these PAGE ITEMS that are set.
2. also, when I click 'Save' to perform the page submit and handle the form DMLs (also done with PL/SQL) I get the following 'session state protection' error:

[image]

I've read many of the questions and blogs about making sure 'Read Only' attribute is 'off' and that 'Disabled' is 'on' with 'Send on Page Submit' is 'on'. I did this and still get the error. I've tried a few different ways (display only, read only, etc...). Is this a bug? I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55613090/cant-disable-session-state-protection-on-oracle-apex-18-1-0-00-45-for-dynamic-a) stack overflow question back with APEX 18.1

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the properties "Disabled" and "Read Only", the field is protected against changes. Since it is disabled, it cannot be changed - so it will throw a session protection error if changed by a dynamic action. This is expected behaviour.

A possible solution is to use the `apex_disabled` css class for the item. That way it cannot be changed by the user but it can be set by a dynamic action. Use "Text Field" or "Number Field" as type.

[image]

Note however, that... whenever an item is editable by a dynamic action it can also be manipulated through javascript, so you need to build in some security to prevent that or catch a creative user.

Comment: Thanks Koen that makes sense. To confirm, for Disabled, the 'Send on Page Submit' attribute is really only to send whatever the "initial" value is when page renders/loads. Outside of your css tip, Is there a better 'APEX' way to do this? Instead of a DA should I use a Page process that reloads the page with the info fetched? I initially didn't do this since it reloads the page and didn't look as nice to the user. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Correct about the the send on page submit. I think the DA is the best solution because it gives the cleanest UI. If you want to use a page process then a multi-page wizard could be a solution.

Comment: ok, thanks that is inline with what I am thinking. something i am thinking, since only 4 page items, any issue in creating 4 identical page items of type 'hidden'. When 'Lookup User' is clicked make part of the DA set these hidden page items and use them when processing? So 1 set is 'Display Only' to show user, and the identical 'Hidden' page itmes are used in the page submit. Any issues you see doing that?

Comment: Depends on how secure you want to make it. Just putting it in a hidden item still makes it vulnerable. Someone can change that value too. You're much better off storing an MD5 hash in a hidden value (one single checksum for all values you want to protect) and recalculate that checksum with current values in a validation. If there is a difference then tampering has been done