# oracle apex with jmeter

Tags: jmeter, oracle-apex

i start to do a loading test with jmeter, i have a form where i can insert record, in the url of insert action there is a parameter called p_json, i do a very basic with table containing one column. the p_json is like this

```
{

"pageItems":{
"itemsToSubmit":[

{

"n":"P13_ROWID",
"v":"",
"ck":"9P9SjzLAQLGkBy_q7phVqLeAJFI"

},
{

"n":"P13_TEST",
"v":"fgjgghjhgjghjghjghjghjghjghj"

}

],
"protected":"QnL4629OYon2MxvQzUtEag",
"rowVersion":"",
"formRegionChecksums":{

}
},
"salt":"188736967333118203740478635219988206060"
```

}

how can i generate ck value in the json, the protected value... in my jmeter request

any documentation of how to do load testing with apex? is there an oracle tool to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41862851/2897748)

> When Value Protected of an hidden item is set to YES a checksum is generated when your page is loaded. When you submit the page with a different value the checksum is not valid anymore and you get the error.

So my expectation is that it is the matter of simple [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter), to wit you need to extract the value from the previous response using a suitable [JMeter Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors), store it into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) and replace this  `QnL4629OYon2MxvQzUtEag` value with the variable.